# Removing triangles and ngons

Tags: modeling

Apparently -- amazingly -- no other question seems to have a similar title to this one.

I will retopologise later, so please don't think this is the final topology.
[image]

I'm trying to remove triangles and ngons in my mesh, but when I remove ngons, it creates a triangle.
[image]

When I remove triangles, by turning them into ngons, it turns any neighboring quads into ngons.
[image]

Using this method doesn't remove triangles and ngons.

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to retopologize later why do you change that geometry now? Generally that's the same process

Comment: To rule out bad geometry being the cause of unwanted creases in the subdivided mesh.

Answer (score 5):

Just for consideration, you have many T-splines around your hole which automatically makes neighboring geometry N-gons (N-gon is every face consisting of 5 or more vertices)

[image]

If you want less messy geometry you should get rid of T-splines. You can do this by dissolving unnecessary edges (some of them are marked in orange on the image below (x -> dissolve edges)). Dissolving edges (also dissolving vertices or faces) is really handy in cases when you are cleaning your own geometry. Also, you should merge some vertices.

[image]

And, most important. Next time you are doing something like this just do this:

1. Make sure that the shape in the middle has same edge count (number of vertices) as a hole that the hole that you are trying to connect it to. If not, fix it by dissolving verticies.

[image]

2. Select both and connect them via bridge edge loops (Ctrl+E -> Bridge edge loops).

[image]

Then if you want more geometry just add subdivision surface (you probably don't have that tight poly budget).

[image]

And one last thing. Don't be so afraid of triangles. It s true that quads are usually better, but sometimes you just gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: "sometimes you just gotta do what you gotta do" - unless you're using MakeClothes for MakeHuman - then "you gotta do as the title says" remove all tris....