# Any help removing a stubborn tri?

Tags: modeling

I've got one stubborn tri on my mesh that wont go away, and was wondering if anyone could cast a quick look at it to see if its possible to make it into a quad?

I want to unwrap the mesh and then texture it in substance painter so I don't want any pinching. I'm still a newbie so forgive me.  I've spent probably too much time on this tri alone (haha) and whilst the [Removing triangles and ngons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84520/removing-triangles-and-ngons/84525) is helpful, it doesn't help me massively.  I've tried with the knife but it ends up solving the problem but creating a new tri or ngon elsewhere.  I've tried loop cuts on either side and up and down but with same result.

Sorry if this is a repeat question

Blend file attached

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Haunt_House, was so obvious I don't know why I didn't see it!

Comment: @obloquy 'obvious', That's the very reason. I focused on the southern part as well. Initially.